# Batch script / sp_executesql

Tags: batch-file

Below I'm trying to execute a batch file that will back up my database, I've been told using sp_executesql is a more secure way of performing this. The problem that i'm having is, I cant figure out what unexpected argument I'm passing from the code below using sqlcmd. I've tried searching for information on it, but have not been able to find anything relevant. This backup is just for a local sqlexpress instance.

```
 SET  spToExec =exec sp_BackupDatabases @databaseName='MY_DB', @backupType='F',@backupLocation='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\'
 ECHO spToExec value is:  %spToExec %
 sqlcmd  -E -S CompName\SQLEXPRESS -Q EXEC sp_executesql spToExec
```

Comment: Try `dqlcmd  -E -S CompName\SQLEXPRESS -Q EXEC sp_executesql %spToExec%`

Comment: did you mean sqlcmd -E -S CompName\SQLEXPRESS -Q EXEC sp_executesql %spToExec%? I tried it, but unfortunately its giving me the same issue.

Comment: `sqlcmd  -E -S CompName\SQLEXPRESS -Q EXEC sp_executesql %spToExec %` note trailing space in `spToExec` variable name if defined as `SET  spToExec =exec …`

Comment: I tried that also Josef, doesn't work. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, the problem had to do with encircling the query with double quotations